# How can I make my sorted list be more efficient?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a method that reads a txt file and I need it to take each word in the text file, and then iterate them in a sorted order, not removing duplicates. I managed to get it working, but would like to get the code to be more efficient. Can someone give me a hinter, what can I do to make it faster? Something other than an ArrayList? Is there another way to sort other than Collections.sort?

```
public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
  ArrayList<String> p = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    int n = 0;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        p.add(line);
        n++;                        
    }       

    Collections.sort(p);
```

Comment: Is there a need to keep track of `n`?

Comment: If you have just this piece of code, then there's nothing more to optimize except for giving an initial size to your `ArrayList` in order to avoid too many internal array resize operations (still, this would be a micro optimization). If you want to optimize the code of your application (that seems to be), then use a profiler to find the real bottleneck instead of guessing where you could do some optimizations.

Comment: You could try a `PriorityQueue` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html which is Java's implementation of a heap. Can't say if it will be more efficient since it has the same big O complexity as sort.

Comment: The performance bottleneck is almost certainly in the reading for lines of text, unless the file is really big (i.e. millions) I suggest you make sure the file is in memory or you get a faster drive.

Comment: Why do you want it to be faster?  Faster than what?  In what way is it too slow.  (Collections.sort() will have been extensively optimized, as will comparison on strings.)  Are you reading millions of lines?  I'd hazard a guess that the sort stage of your code is marginal compared to your input and (since you have a PrintWriter) output stages.  Have you measured each stage for comparison?

Comment: Also, how big is your BufferedReader's buffer?  Have you tried making it bigger?

Comment: I've posted a method on how to sort it recursively. I saw a pretty good  decease in execution time when sorting a large Arraylist of Strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option would be to use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) that maps words to their frequencies.

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> words = new TreeMap<>();

while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    for (String word : line.split("\\s+")) {
        if (words.containsKey(line))
            words.put(line, words.get(line) + 1);
        else
            words.put(line, 1);  
    }                 
}
```

It's difficult if not impossible to tell which option will be more efficient without knowing the details of the file you'll be reading, and ultimately timing both variants.

Having said that, it is likely that using a `Map` will be preferable in terms of memory. There's no need to store and have to deal with multiple copies of the *same* word in your collection, it makes more sense to store just one and have with it an associated frequency.

Comment: Have you tested if this option enhances the performance or just an idea?

Comment: OP says that he doesn't want to remove duplicates. `TreeMap` doesn't allow duplicates.

Comment: I don't think this will be better... `put` is a `log(n)` operation. With `n` words we will arrive at `nlog(n)` time, the same as `Collections.Sort`

Comment: @RafiKamal That's why we map to a frequency.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza "Better" was a strong word, I agree. I made some edits.

Comment: @Shoe This will likely be more memory efficient.

Comment: @arshajii The question asks about making it "faster". Though, the asker should have been more explicit about how they want it "more efficient".